# apache authentication

Tags: apache-2.2, authentication, mod-auth

I'm trying to set up a local webserver on my network.  I want to be able to be able to access the webserver from any machine inside my network w/out authenticating.  and two extra domains need access to it w/out authenticating.  Everyone else I would like to authenticate in. so far, I can get to it from inside my network. and the two extra domains can access my webserver, but everyone else is just hanging.  They don't get an authentication or anything.

can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

This is part of my apache's site-available file so far:

```
<Directory /path/to/server/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks -Multiviews
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from All
    Allow from 192.168
    Allow from localhost
    Allow from domain1
    Allow from domain2
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "my authentication"
    AuthUserFile /path/to/file
    Require valid-user
    Satisfy Any
    AllowOverride All
    <Files .htaccess>
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from All
    </Files>
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tracked down my problem to me being VPN'd into work.  As soon as I disconnect from the VPN, everything works as expected.  I now have to figure out why that is causing everything to hang when not from inside the network or domain1/2.